# Are PHP config files secure on HTTP?

Tags: php, security, http, encryption, config

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Security of PHP script, embedded or otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679061/security-of-php-script-embedded-or-otherwise)

Many PHP apps available for download (Wordpress, for example) contain configuration files including sensitive information (passwords, database login details, etc.). Are these files really secure? I know if someone navigates to them directly or tries to download them (via http://www.example.com/admin/config.php for example) all they will see is a blank page without any data on it. However, I am still wary. Might you be able to enlighten me regarding file security best practices in this regard? Thank you!

Comment: View the page source. Nothing important there. Unless the server doesn't parse the php, you're fine. If it doesn't, you've got a bigger problem than a user knowing your database password (It's probably screwed anyway if they can see any of your source)

Comment: The general advise is to move sensitive config files above the document root. A simpler approach is using a restricted subdirectory or previnting access with an .htaccess and FilesMatch directive.

Comment: @mario: The question is related but different in that I am asking about dedicated PHP config files not HTML files with PHP content embedded. Thanks for the .htaccess and FilesMatch tips. I'll look into this.

Comment: @Jared: You can certainly find a "more exact" duplicate without any question filler about HTML. But it's the same topic, and there aren't many more (practical) solutions I believe.

Comment: @mario: Got it. I'll look more carefully next time before posting my question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are typically safe.  However, best is to include the configuration file from above the public_html folder so direct access is not possible.  Otherwise there are tons of other ways to keep them safe.

Comment: I will definitely place it above the public_html folder. Mario mentions defining the .htaccess file as well. Would it help to obfuscate the database name, password, etc. in some way?

Comment: Sounds like you are worried about potential password fallout.  Why not just use something like ioncube as well?

Comment: Thanks, David. These comments give me some options to explore.

Answer (score 1):

In general, they are save. But if somehow possible, they should be moved to a directory not reachable from the web, because if for whatever reason the php parser stops working and spits out plaintext sourcecode, your configs wont be visible.